# firstname and lastname validator by regex in android

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a problem to validate a name by this regex:

```java
public static boolean validateNames(Context context, String txt) {
    String regx = "():@#$%&_+\*=~^`“‘,.:;!?/\{}\[]<>0123456789*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

When I launch the test, an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{ma.altensoftwareawards.mbo/ma.altensoftwareawards.mbo.activities.SplashActivity}:
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern
near index 28:
        ():@#$%&_+\*=~^`“‘,.:;!?/\{}\[\]<>0123456789*$
```

exactly on `[`.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes (use "\\" instead of just "\"). Your regex  seems wrong regardless of that. What are you trying to match?

Comment: thank you for your help ,I'm trying to match a name

Comment: I heve replaced '\' by '\\' and the same problem showing

Comment: +user2934536 try my solution

Comment: I figured that much :) For example, to match my name, you'd need a regex looking like "Dima" ... But this is probably not it, right?  I mean what kind of pattern you are trying to match  with your regex, because the regex you wrote in the question does not make any sense. I really doubt it does what you want to do.

Comment: +Dima I think he is trying to match any non alphabets using the hard way :)

Comment: This regex does not match "any nonalphabets". Also, I have never seen a "first name" or "last name", that would contain numbers, slashes or asterisks.

Comment: +Dima why doesn't it? It matches any non letters and therefore trying to see if the username is invalid? Use your logic

Comment: It does not. It matches (I mean, it would if the problems with escaping were sorted out) strings, that contain an exact sequence of those gibberish characters, followed by any number of nines at the end of the string. And it returns `true` when match is found.

Comment: thank you for your helps,what is the best way to do it?

Comment: @user293456 you'd have to explain what it is you are trying to do, using actual words.

Comment: @Dima ,the name that i have to validate must start by a letter and not content any character of these   ():@#$%&_+*=~^`“‘,.:;!?/{}[]<>0123456789*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException** means that your regex is incorrect. It seems like that you are trying to see if there is any illegal characters in the name. It's easier to do that this way instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
return matcher.find();
```

This match any NON ALPHABET instead of all that gibberish.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:
Due to OP's request, here is how it should look(readers, please refer to above section if you do not have restrictions on how your regex should look):**

```
String regex = "[():@#$%&_+\\*=~^`“‘,.:;!?/\\{}\\[\\]<>0123456789*$]+";
```

Then you can compile it. This is the working regex that you need.

Comment: This matches all strings that do not start with a letter. Doubt that's what the OP wants.

Comment: this solution work fine, but i have to use this regex ():@#$%&_+*=~^`“‘,.:;!?/\{}[]<>0123456789*$

Comment: +Dima not "that do not start with a letter" but "that do not contain a letter". Try it yourself.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Not "do not contain a letter", but "contain a non-letter" :)

Comment: +Dima yeah, and that match the OP's question :-)

Comment: this is a specification of the project that i work on it

Comment: so this regex is wrong,that is?

Comment: Yes, but you can modify it to make it right

Comment: @TheProgrammer is it? :) I am still not sure if  it is. For example "joHN" does not look like a name to me, while, for example, "O'Hara" does ...

Comment: @Dima This is not what the OP intended. The OP's regex will say false for joHN and true for O'Hara

Comment: @TheProgrammer No, his regex will say `false` for both (as well as for most other inputs, see my last comment to the original question). I have no idea what he intended.

Comment: @Dima No. It will say true for joHN but false for O'Hara because there is an ' in the second name but no gibberish in the first name.

Comment: @TheProgrammer no it will say false for both. I am talking about OP's regex from his question, not yours. Try it, it's not doing what you seem tio think it should, not even close.

Comment: @Dima It's not possible with his regex, it's wrong :)

Comment: @TheProgrammer my point exactly :) The regex does not make any sense, and so there is absolutely no way to tell what his intent is. All we know is that "he wants to match names". O'Hara is a name ...